# Ad Hoc using C#

Tags: c#, adhoc

I am using Windows 8 and ended up realizing that he no longer has support for creating Ad Hoc networks. The only possible way to create such a network is by console command:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=alow ssid=ssid key=key
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I started doing a program in C# using a function that executed the command console using this example: [Execute Shell Command using C#](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Execute-Shell-Commands-from-Net.html)

Unfortunately some commands only work in administrator mode, and I could not get the console commands work as an administrator directly by code.

**Here's my question:** 
Is there any library or API in C # to create an Ad Hoc network?

Comment: Are you running your program as Administrator?  If you're running it in the debugger then running the debugger as Administrator will cause your program to as well.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes, I just found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815252(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin Ok, I'm a little embarrassed now, because it worked well. Thank you. You can add as a final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your program as Administrator? If you're running it in the debugger then running the debugger as Administrator will cause your program to as well.